# How to hide data label of Chartkick Piechart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pie-chart, chartkick

Dears, I am new to Rails development, and now try to use Chartkick to show a pie chart.

I uses Highchart by adding require highchart in application.js. Everything goes well except the data labels. I try to hide them but they are always there.

The original code is like:

```
new Chartkick.PieChart("changepie", {"WithoutChange":<%=@count_noChange%>,"WithChange":<%=@count_change%>}, {"colors":["#FF9900","#3366CC"]});
```

As answered in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592466/how-to-hide-labels-in-the-highcharts-in-the-pie#_=_), I added

```
new Chartkick.PieChart("changepie", {"WithoutChange":<%=@count_noChange%>,"WithChange":<%=@count_change%>}, {"colors":["#FF9900","#3366CC"]}, {"library": { "plotOptions": { "pie": { "allowPointSelect": true, "cursor": "pointer", "dataLabels": { "enabled": false}, "showInLegend": true}}}} );
```

But the data label is still there? 
Could you please advise how to specify the options when creating a pie chart to hide data label?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
pie_chart data, library: {plotOptions: { pie: { dataLabels: { enabled: false }}}}
```